# How can I pass parameters to another tab navigation screen

Tags: react-native

Hi guys I'm still new to react native, I wanted to ask how can I pass a parameter to another screen? I'm currently doing a login system which going to access the email of the user and show their email on their profile page after they logged in. I've tried `{ this.props.navigation.state.params.Email }` in the **profile.js** but it shows an error says that

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.state.params')

I saw some related solutions as well but those were for stack navigator but I'm using bottom tab navigation so I wasn't sure if they work in the same way.

**login.js**

`this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile', { Email: email });`

**app.js**

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={getTransaction} />
        <Tab.Screen name="addTransaction" component={addTransaction} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Register" component={register} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Login" component={login} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={profile} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

I believe you should get the params from props.router instead of props.navigation.

Answer (score 2):

in your Profile screen page:

```
export const profile = ({route}) => {

const { Email } = route.params;

}
```

Then you can use 'Email' as a regular constant.